# Why Lay is weaker than Kanon if he's his reincarnation?

Tags: mao-gakuin-no-futekigosha

Supposedly Lay is the reincarnation of Kanon. Kanon was supposed to be a match for Anon, or may be even stronger since Anon states Kanon's mastery of root magic surpasses even his own. But when reincarnated Anon defeats Lay with a stick.

Why Lay is weaker than Kanon if he's his reincarnation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He only reincarnated with 1 source not all 7 he fused the other 6 with the demon emperors to wipe their memories and create a fake demon king Avos so that the humans wouldn’t know the real demon king when he reincarnated that’s also why Melheis has his memory Kanon couldn’t use his last source to change his memory or he wouldn’t be able to come back